# Use PHP htmlentities to convert special characters to their entity number rather than entity name

Tags: php, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

How do you force PHP "**htmlentities**" to convert a special character to the entity *number* rather than to the entity *name*?

For example, convert **É** to **&#201** rather than to **&Eacute**

I have searched with no answers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't can force PHP "htmlentities"  to convert a special character to the entity number rather than to the entity name.
Take a user function.

```
function htmlEntityNumber($char){
  $utf32char = mb_convert_encoding($char,"UTF-32BE","UTF-8");
  return "&#".unpack("N",$utf32char)[1] . ";";
}

//var_dump and echo only show an É
debug::write(htmlEntityNumber('É'));  
//string(5) ASCII   "&#201"
```